# Redirecting files from a directory using awk

Tags: awk

I am running an awk command for every text file in a directory. As of now it displays to stdout. I will like it to save those changes to the actual files themselves. My command is

`awk{ORS=(/^\-  **\ **/?"":RS)}1 *.txt >> *.txt`

Every time I redirect the command it saves everything into one file. Is there anyway I can save the changes back to the files themselves?

Comment: This is a shell issue so update your tags to show whatever shell you are using. `>>` means `append`. Did you mean that or did you really want `>` which means `overwrite`? Also, what version of awk are you using and do you have GNU awk available (`awk --version`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-`s and blanks aren't regexp metacharacters outside of bracket expressions so no need to escape them in your regexp. You do need to enclose your script in single quote delimiters though. This will do what your script is apparently trying to do:

```
awk '{ORS=(/^-  ** **/?"":RS)}1'
```

You cannot write to the same file you are reading. If you try to do that with any command (awk, sed, grep, whatever):

```
command file > file
```

then the shell can do whatever it likes, including executing `> file` before `command file` and so emptying the file before your command opens it.

To overwrite the input file with GNU awk 4.* would be:

```
awk -i inplace '{ORS=(/^-  ** **/?"":RS)}1' *.txt
```

and with other awks you'd need something like:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    awk '{ORS=(/^-  ** **/?"":RS)}1' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

Comment: The for loop worked but now each file blank line space has been removed giving me a chunk of data for each file. It appears its trying to put everything into one line.

Comment: The awk script does what you wrote it to do, adding output redirection doesn't change that at all. If it's doing something you didn't want it to do then test it on one file and fix it to do what you want it to do. For example, you would want to escape the `*`s in it if you want them to be treated literally.